# New Gaussian complex number

Tags: complex-numbers, gaussian-integers

I was told that along with introducing $a+bi$ notation for complex numbers, Gauss was also working on $a+bi+ci^2$ type numbers, which he subsequently abandoned. I would be grateful if anyone can point me to any books, papers, publications which can shed some more light on this?

Thanks

Comment: You can search in google for quaternion numbers .

Comment: Why, many great minds worked on numbers of similar form, but never quite reached any good. Then [Frobenius theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_theorem_(real_division_algebras)) came along and put an end to that.

Comment: Then again, maybe you were talking about the [Eisenstein integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein_integer)? That's another story altogether.

Comment: Thanks all for your prompt responses. I quickly skimmed both Quaternions and Eisenstein integers in wikipedia and both look vaguely relevant, but not quite. I am using such expressions for general solutions of high degree polynomials. I'm in the process of compiling a research paper for publication... so fingers crossed. Thanks @Beslikas Thannos Ivan Neretin

Comment: Good luck with your paper !!! :D